# Firefox gives "The certificate is not trusted"

Tags: firefox, tomcat, ssl, ssl-certificate

I'm using Tomcat 7, with APR and a DigiCert signed "star" certificate for my org. I have a connector defined like:

```
<Connector
           protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           port="8443" maxThreads="200"
           scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
           SSLCertificateFile="/opt/certs/star.crt"
           SSLCertificateKeyFile="/opt/certs/star.key"
           SSLCertificateChainFile="/opt/certs/DigiCertCA.crt"
           SSLCACertificateFile="/opt/certs/star.pem"
           SSLVerifyClient="none" SSLProtocol="all"
           keypass="******" 
           />
```

IE and Chrome have no issues with my site/certs...Firefox though gives this warning, which searching online seems to be common:

```
The certificate is not trusted because no issuer chain was provided. (Error code: sec_error_unknown_issuer)
```

Also, when I run this openssl command:

```
openssl s_client -connect myorf.org:443 -showcerts
```

I do get a message at the end of the output which says:

```
Verify return code: 21 (unable to verify the first certificate)
```

So apparently there is some problem with the chain...I just don't know what nor how to fix this. One search brought up this answer to return code 21:

```
you have a problem with certificate installation and you have to re-install it properly.
```

But when I installed my certs they reported successful, so I'm just not sure what I am missing to make Firefox happy...help please...?

Comment: As Steffen alluded to: provide a URL so we can test it. `myorf.org` does not appear to be a real site. Use `example.com` instead because its reserved by IANA for that purpose. Folks like Steffen, Bruno and EJP can usually pinpoint the problem in under 30 seconds. But we need something to look at.

Comment: Looking at [DigiCert Trusted Root Authority Certificates](https://www.digicert.com/digicert-root-certificates.htm), there is no file named `DigiCertCA.crt`. You really need to provide more information and accurate information. Its difficult to guess when we get bad information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check you DigiCertCA.crt file that it contains all necessary intermediate certificates you got and is also in PEM format. Check also the apache log file for errors (maybe it failed to load the certificates).

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply. Sorry in advance for my ignorance. As I understand it the DigiCertCA.crt is the intermediate...? When I downloaded "all certificates" from DigiCert I got the DigicertCA.crt and my own .crt. I have no apache log file...I'm using Tomcat with APR. Tomcat shows no errors. How would I check if the "DigiCertCA.crt file that it contains all necessary intermediate certificates you got"? In the meantime, I'll try converting it to pem and see what happens.

Comment: To check if everything is there you can `openssl verify`. Give it the certificate, a list of untrusted certificates (which should be your chain file) with option `-untrusted` and the trusted DigiCert Root-CA (which is included in the browser and should not be included in the chain file, you can export it from the browser) with `-CAfile`. If the verification succeeds your chain probably contains the correct certificates.  You can also check with `openssl s_client` against your server - it shows which certificates are sent.